Why am I getting NoMethodError (undefined method `user_id' for an instance of AppTransaction) in rails?
Whenever I try to save or update my AppTransaction model, it doesn't let me. It was working before I added the account system, and then it started giving me an error about there not being a user_id method for app_transactions. Do you guys know why?
Error
undefined method `user_id' for an instance of AppTransaction
Extracted source (around line #34):
`
@transaction = @account.app_transactions.build(transaction_params)
if @transaction.save <- this is line 34
  redirect_to account_app_transactions_path @account
else
  render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity`

AppTransactions#create
def create
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @account = @user.accounts.find(params[:account_id])
    @transaction = @account.app_transactions.build(transaction_params)

    if @transaction.save
      redirect_to account_app_transactions_path @account
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end

transaction_params
def transaction_params
    params.expect(app_transaction: [ :amount, :category, :date, :summary, :details, :is_income ])
end

user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :accounts, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
end

account.rb
class Account < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :app_transactions, dependent: :destroy
end

app_transaction.rb
class AppTransaction < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :account
end

Columns for AppTransaction
AppTransaction(id: integer, amount: float, category: string, date: datetime, account_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, summary: string, details: text, is_income: boolean)

I've tried replacing .save with .save!, doing @user.accounts.find() vs. Accounts.find(), and messing with the app_transaction.rb file, but I still get the same error every time.

The problem with this question is that the code given doesn't actually reproduce the error. That means the the actual problem is something outside of the question hiding in the margins - like for example that you might not be working on the version of the file that you think or other "programmer related errors". Try to extract out the minimum needed to reproduce it and write a test that reproduces the issue. By doing so you'll most likely solve the issue yourself.

@max Thanks, I'll try that. I'm thinking that it might be that I renamed my references column without actually changing the references, but I tried running the migration to fix it and the test still failed.

just search for user_id or user on models/app_transaction.rb

are you using spring by any chance?

The problem with the question is that it doesn't give full information to see where the issue is
I would double-check that Accounts has a user_id column(foreign key) in the database.
Or the Migration of Accounts table should be
On table creation, it should have
t.belongs_to :user

or
 t.references :user

This will create a user_id column in the accounts
To test you can create Accounts using the rails console.
rails c
Account.create!(...require_fields)

